# Trouble checking in paths which include parentheses

Tags: svn

If I check a directory out of a svn repository, and the path inside the repository contains parentheses, I get a svn 'Commit failed' message when I try to check the working directory back in.

I'm aware that using parentheses in path names is not good practice; I'm just trying to clean up someone else's mess.

Here's an example of checking out such a repository:

```
$ svn co http://cvs.xyzzy.com/svn/ie/Userhome/bchittenden/Test%20%28With%20Stupid%20Parentheses%29/
A    Test (With Stupid Parentheses)/foo
A    Test (With Stupid Parentheses)/bar
A    Test (With Stupid Parentheses)/baz
Checked out revision 61793.
```

When I try to commit, I get the following message:

```
$ svn ci
Adding         branches
Adding         tags
Adding         trunk
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: A MERGE response for '/svn/ie/Userhome/bchittenden/Test%20(With%20Stupid%20Parentheses)/tags' is not a child of the destination ('/svn/ie/Userhome/bchittenden/Test%20%28With%20Stupid%20Parentheses%29')
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn:    '/tmp/Test (With Stupid Parentheses)/svn-commit.tmp'
```

Note that the changes *do* get checked into the repository, and I can check out a fresh version of the repository and do work there, but I'll get the same message when I try to check that in.

If I'm interpreting this correctly, the SVN server isn't correctly URL encoding the '(' and ')' characters in the path name when it tries to validate the names of the files being committed. I tried several Google searches on the error message `is not a child of the destination`, but couldn't find a workaround.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Just to make sure: You *did* install the latest version everywhere?

Comment: svnserv is ancient (it's a 2009 compile). I don't own it, however I've found a workaround; see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run `svn info | grep URL` on the working directory as I checked it out, I get

```
$ svn info | grep URL
URL: http://cvs.xyzzy.com/svn/ie/Userhome/bchittenden/Test%20%28With%20Stupid%20Parentheses%29
```

This matches the second part of the SVN MERGE response, i.e. the client side. It turns out, I can use `svn switch` to change the URL to resolve the conflict:

```
$ svn switch 'http://cvs.xyzzy.com/svn/ie/Userhome/bchittenden/Test%20(With%20Stupid%20Parentheses)'
E    trunk
E    branches
E    tags
Updated to revision 61900.
```

now the URL matches the first part of the SVN MERGE response (i.e. the server side), and there is no conflict.

```
$ svn info | grep URL
URL: http://cvs.xyzzy.com/svn/ie/Userhome/bchittenden/Test%20(With%20Stupid%20Parentheses)
```

After this, if I change the file 'bar', and check it in, the changes get committed correctly:

```
$ svn ci -m 'changed bar'
Sending        bar
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 61901.
```